# define work $W=\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$

Tags: calculus, physics, line-integrals

We define work as follows :
$$W=\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$$
and we know that $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t),\mathbf{v}(t),t)$ now can we write ? :
$$W=\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}\overset{?}{=}\int_C \mathbf{F}(t)\cdot \mathbf{v}(t)\, dt $$

Comment: Yes, that's from the definition of a line integral like $\int_C\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister how prove  ?

Comment: You almost don't need to prove anything! If you just note that $\dot{\mathbf{r}}=\mathbf{v},$ you invoke the definition, and you're done.

Comment: $d \vec r = \vec v dt$